# Does the Highcharts-Vue wrapper support 'gauge' and 'heatmap' chart types?

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue

I don't see examples of these in the demo and there is nothing mentioned in the docs. I'm wondering if it is simply not possible or just not demoed because of their more complicated nature.

I will also need to use Charts *appendData* prototype to make a line chart real-time. Is this possible using the wrapper? I'm thrown by the following in the docs but not sure it it's directly related;

> You can access the Chart object instance if necessary (e.g when need
>   to get some data or use any of Chart.prototype functions), by calling
>   specific Vue component instance chart field, but it is not supported
>   to update the chart using its built-in functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the `highcharts-vue` package supports all official modules included in Highcharts, so it's not necessary to produce every demo from demos site using Vue wrapper. I made the examples with `gauge` and `heatmap`series specially for you, so please take a look on them.

> I will also need to use Charts appendData prototype to make a line chart real-time. Is this possible using the wrapper?

A component is watching for changes on provided chart configuration, so if you will update your data (e.g by pushing new points into a `series.data`), then `highcharts-vue` will detect it, and automatically update the chart. That's the most recommended way of implementation. If you would like to use some `Chart`'s or `Series` prototype functions, of course you can do that, but please note that causes inconsistency between the chart data and the data defined within component. Just need to access chart's reference like it is described in [Chart object reference](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue#chart-object-reference) section.

Live examples:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-uqu1p (Gauge),
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-8z2f5 (Heatmap)

Comment: Wow! This is super helpful. Thank you @daniel_s for your efforts.

Comment: Enjoy the wrapper ;)

Comment: Hey @daniel_s, because I needed to update two charts from a single ajax response, I could not get your example to work for me in an elegant way. I managed to get it working using the following example where a reference to the chart is used for the update. Do you see any issue with doing it this way instead of using the callback function?
https://codesandbox.io/s/jjyqvv0k13

Comment: It should also work properly, because there is no any chart data kept in component data. You're just downloading the data using AJAX, and update the chart, so it does not affect on anything else.